# Do I need to modify my existing csproj or add a project.json file to a command project that references a new .net standard library?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-standard

I have recently made the decision to try and re-standardise my older style PCL's from the (apparently archaic) old approach of `portable-net451+win81+wpa81` to now `netstandard1.x`. I took this decision as Xamarin Forms on my Mac was no longer recognising one of my libraries as a NuGet package.

Anyway, having started this conversion I have entered a world of unknown pain in the sense that it isn't a very automatic process. I'm now at the stage where I think I've converted my PCL's to net standard libraries but now I'm trying to reference these standards within a 'normal' windows console app I get odd errors.

Primarily my errors are thus:

> Error CS0012: The type `System.Linq.IQueryable 1<TItem>` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` (CS0012)
>
> Error CS0012: The type `System.Collections.IEnumerable` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` (CS0012) (Redbridge.Console)

Now given that my project is referencing one of my net standard libraries and this error originates from me using a class that requires packages `System.Linq.Queryable` and `System.Linq` to be added specifically to my net standard library I can't help but wonder how I'm meant to make this work in my console app library. I note that the versions are `.20` rather than the standard `.0` so what do I do to make this work?

I've tried the obvious (referencing the above packages in my console app as suggested by the compiler) but to no effect. Does anyone have any advice? Do I need to add a project.json file for example to my console app so that I can indicate that `.NET` standard should be used or something?

I've read quite a bit on the `.NET` standard and like most find it confusing as to what I'm expected to do.